# HTML5 web app not caching when added to home screen on iOS

Tags: ios, html, caching, application-cache

I have web application ASP/MVC which uses application cache and it has to work as standalone application when added to home screen. It works fine, but on iOS10 it doesn't cache and doesn't work on offline mode. I don't have exact steps but it seems like it stops workign when i add this application for second/third time:
1 I add application to home screen and it works properly
2 I add this application to home screen again - it doesn't work
And all next installed applications doesn't work.

Also i wasn't able to reproduce it on one of the test servers.

I would try to clen cache (maybe it would help) but because of atandalone applications are opened not in Safary on iPhone - i don't know how to do this.

Also i found script to debug application cache
https://jonathanstark.com/blog/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache?filename=2009/09/27/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache/
But when i run application which doesn't work in offline mode - it simply doesn't enter in any of events handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was. There was redirecting on another page on my site and you could redirect even if application cache is still loading content so the caching stops and after redirecting back we on purpose setted manifest to empty string (it turned out like a feature that after redirecting back caching doesn't start being loaded). But on another OS caching started loading according to previous manifest, and only for iOS 10 if manifest turns out to empty string - caching doesn't start.